# Is $0$ a limit point of the sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$, where $a_n:=(-1)^{3n+1}10^{-(3n+1)}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Consider the sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$, where $a_n:=(-1)^{3n+1}10^{-(3n+1)}$. Is $0$ a limit point for that sequence?

I see that, this sequence is "wandering" around $0$ and is bounded by $1$, and that hints me that 0 is possibly a limit point, though I tried to prove that via the definition by assuming some arbitrary $ε>0$ and $N\ge 0$, and so all that is left to show is to find some $n\ge N$ such that $|a_n-0|<ε$, or equivalently $10^{-(3n+1)}<ε$. But, I'm left utterly stumped. Also, I think that the inequality $10^{-m}<\frac{1}{m}$ is important to know.

Any suggestions as to how I could further proceed with this?

Comment: Just take logs on both sides.

Comment: "the inequality $10^{-m}<\frac{1}{m}$ is important to know": indeed, and sufficient to conclude.

Comment: @Vaskara_GRek_O, it is a duplicate question, please remove it.

Comment: $0$ is not just a limit point, it is the l8mit of the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You've almost completed it. So continuing where you left of we can see:
$$10^{-(3n+1)}<10^{-n}<\frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon$$

Hence we conclude that $\forall\varepsilon>0$ and $N\ge 0$, $\exists n\ge N, n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|(-1)^{3n+1}10^{-(3n+1)}-0|<\varepsilon$.